# Android multiple ContentProviders with same database name throws 'no such table' exception

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

When using same database name for multiple ContentProviders, query fails with exception thrown as 'no such table'.

I researched the reference, and books, the Internet discussions, but could not find resolution.

I noticed that all the ContentProviders fail except the one ContentProvider declared first in the manifest. So I gave unique database name and the exception goes away. It works but it's weird to have multiple single-table databases.

I want to figure out why the problem occurs if possible. Below is my implementation in essence.

All ContentProviders have separate SQLiteOpenHelper defined as inner private class. DATABASE_NAME and DATABASE_VERSION are all the same.

```
public class TheFirstProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbname.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate(){
        mContext = getContext();
        dbHelper = new FirstDbHelper(mContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    private class FirstDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
         ...
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_FIRST = ... ;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_FIRST);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     private class FirstDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{      
     public FirstDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String query="Your Query";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Set your Code as below.It will Work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Create table statement and verify if it was correctly executed and see if the table you are using on the query has the exact same name as the one created. Sometimes a little mistake on the DDL (create statement) lead to problems like this that happens silently.

I also suggest you to install this [eclipse plugin](http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/browse-android-emulator-sqlite-database-eclipse) to visualize the database on your emulator so you can see the tables you have created and check if it's what you've expected.

Comment: Oh, I indeed spent quite amount of time checking the statement. But I reached a conclusion that the statement is not the problem since no Log reported during onCreate().